# Supplied action failed with an exception in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Today, I opened my project. While running this debug build, two exceptions came. It doesn’t affect the build or debug build; it runs perfectly. But in the Android folder two errors are shown,

[image]

What is this?

Exception:

> The supplied phased action failed with an exception. Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileDebugUnitTestSources'. this and base files have different roots: D:\factory\spotless\build\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle and C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.6\android.

Versions:

- Flutter 3.0.5
- channel stable
- Dart 2.17.6

Comment: Is it the same after running flutter clean ?

Comment: yes , i did flutter clean , flutter repair etc ..... but nothing works

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This issue came from the *[Extensions Language Support for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java)* by [Red Hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux):

[image]

In the new version of these Extensions it has the above bug.

That is

> The supplied phased action failed with an exception. Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileDebugUnitTestSources'. this and base files have different roots: D:\factory\spotless\build\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle and C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.6\android.

To solve this, I downgraded *Extensions Language Support for Java* by Red Hat the extensions (1.9.0 to 1.8.0).

or

remove/disable the extensions

[image]

Comment: I have the same error with Thread Starter for more than a week, and found out your solution, then disable the Extensions. Voila. It never goes error anymore. Thank you @Jinto

Answer (score 0):

I disabled 'Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat' extension and the error is gone